# how to load html file in ImGear accusoft?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert html file into pdf document.

but, it fails to load html file with error format not supported.
can anyone help on how to load html file using accusoft?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the library you're using documented to support HTML->PDF conversions?

Comment: @Llama it supports for the image to pdf. I am checking if HTML to pdf supported or not?

Comment: You mean you've contacted Accusoft's support to ask? Or you're asking us on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Llama stackoverflow

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask Accusoft? Considering it errors saying it failed to load the HTML file due to a format error, it points to them not supporting it.

Comment: yes, @Llama I have asked there also.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `Accusoft` cannot load the HTML file in their product.
In the Accusoft there is a product called `PrizmDoc` Suite.
The Loading HTML file comes under `PrizmDoc Viewer`.
Currently the product has no specific controls to load the HTML file.
The detailed information is [here](https://www.accusoft.com/faqs/can-prizmdoc-viewer-load-html-documents-with-utf-8/)

So you cannot convert the PDF from HTML using the Accusoft.

But there is another way provided in the link that this can be fixed manually.
Change the charset = `“utf-8”` to the `meta` tag of the HTML document.
Your problem may be rectified by this method.

Comment: please, @Arun can you share the link?

Comment: https://www.accusoft.com/faqs/can-prizmdoc-viewer-load-html-documents-with-utf-8/